# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForDebug'. > android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Unable to build apk in Android Studio.
I have tried to CLEAN/INVALIDATE CACHE/REBUILD and all other common measures.

Previously I added a proxy class for `ActionBarActivity` to suppport one of my dependencies(`Hotline.io`) but now I don't need the proxy class and I deleted it. After that I keep getting this very irritating error! Please help

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForDebug'.>android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity
```

My Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ahija.com"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 24
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // GOOGLE
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

    // PLAY SERVICES
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'

    // FIREBASE
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'

    // FACEBOOK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'

    // OTHERS
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation:bottom-navigation:2.0.1-rc1'
    compile 'com.github.zurche:open-weather-map-android-wrapper:v0.1'
    compile 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'de.cketti.mailto:email-intent-builder:1.0.0'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.DamanSingh4321:ProProgressViews:v1.1'
    compile group: 'com.cloudinary', name: 'cloudinary-android', version: '1.20.0'

    // INTEGRATIONS
    compile 'com.github.freshdesk:hotline-android:1.2.5'

    // NEW AND COOL
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'

    // ANNOTATION PROCESSORS
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // TEST
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help!

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is dead

Answer (score 1):

Use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`